# Why does Git Push --mirror require a non detached head?

Tags: git, push, head, mirror

I've noticed that git push --mirror requires a proper repository state.  This doesn't make sense to me  , since mirroring all references should be able to occur regardless of where the HEAD is pointed at.  Any thoughts on how to make git push --mirror work on any sort of repository ?  I find that currently, I have to do something like

git pull

git checkout master

git push --mirror secondrepo

Which "feels" like its overkill given the simple and transparent branching model that git follows.  It seems like mirror pushes should be doable from any repository state.

Comment: It looks like a bug that may have been fixed in 1.8.4+, as the push logic that forbids detached HEAD state has changed.  Not that I have tested this...

Comment: @torek I don't see that anywhere in the release notes...is it in the commit messages for the Git repo anywhere?

Comment: @Cupcake: it's not in release notes and I didn't see it in commit messages.  I'm not actually sure it was changed, I just looked at the most recent code to see where detached-HEAD state was checked and that code has changed a lot due to the other changes for push.  It looks as though the new code path checks *after* checking various mirror ops, which would have the side effect of fixing it, just as a matter of cleaning up the code. :-)